# Global static Variable/Properties Across whole application

Tags: c#, design-patterns, xamarin.forms

What i'm trying to Achieve:

Have a single Class Housing a Class for every View then That ViewClass housing every Property Or Variable In a static Format, So that I don't have to Create a new instance of that Class every-time, So I can Pass Data from View to View Neatly.

Or am I thinking of this Completely Wrong?

This Class would have to Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface So I cant just make the class static And go from there.

Comment: Static classes are generally a bad idea to use to hold state. It makes your code very hard to test and creates a lot of dependencies that you could avoid but sending instances that hold state.

Comment: So how els would I Hold state without having to constantly Reinitialise Classes and potentially  reset them ?

Comment: Use DependencyInjection and register such class as a Singleton to the DI-Container.

Comment: Why did I not know Singletons exist, And Yes DependencyInjection was my next learning step So I will get on that! Thank you guys.